# Check for the existence of a file: URL that uses URLEncoding in Tcl 8.5.9

Tags: tcl, urlencode, urldecode

What is the simplest way to check for the existence of a file specified by a `file:` URL that uses URLEncoding in Tcl 8.5.9?

`::http::geturl` says it doesn't support `file` URLs.

`file exists` requires URLDecoding. There doesn't seem to be a builtin proc for URLDecoding. Have I missed it?

Are there any other builtin ways to do this? Do newer versions of Tcl provide more support for this?

If no builtin way, is there a recommended library for this? Either for directly handling `file:` URLs, or for URLDecoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my projects, I tend to use a combination of a URI/URL processor ([uri::split](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/uri/uri.html#2)) plus a URL decoder ([urlDecode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/URL_decoding#Tcl)) for postprocessing:

### Step 1: URL processing

```
% package req uri
1.2.7
% set parsedURL [::uri::split file:///path/to/a%20file]
path /path/to/a%20file scheme file
```

### Step 2: URL (percent-) decoding

Source the following:

```
proc urlDecode {str} {
    set specialMap {"[" "%5B" "]" "%5D"}
    set seqRE {%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})}
    set replacement {[format "%c" [scan "\1" "%2x"]]}
    set modStr [regsub -all $seqRE [string map $specialMap $str] $replacement]
    return [encoding convertfrom utf-8 [subst -nobackslash -novariable $modStr]]
}
```

Then:

```
% set fp [urlDecode [dict get $parsedURL path]]
/path/to/a file
% file exists $fp
% 0
```

Depending on the portability and robustness aimed at, you might want to use `file normalize` & friends.

Comment: Note: Tcl 8.5 is way beyond end of life. You might want to consider upgrading to 8.6?

Comment: I’m using a third-party application that uses the out-of-date Tcl for scripting in its current version, so I cannot upgrade Tcl. Hopefully, they’ll finally upgrade at some point.

Comment: I see. Still, the above will work for you: the `uri` package in `tcllib` and the `urlDecode` proc are 8.5 ready.